# ThreeJS: Shader UVs not defined if glTF model contains no texture

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm importing a glTF model that contains a UV set, and I want to assign a texture to it dynamically in ThreeJS by injecting shader code into the existing using `onBeforeCompile()`.

So far everything works, however if I remove the test texture from the model in Blender and re-export it, then the shader refuses to compile with a `vUv undeclared identifier` error. When viewing the geometry buffer attributes in the debugging console, the UV maps seem to be defined, but aren't getting defined in the shader for some reason.

I don't want to export the model with a texture, that would mean loading the texture twice (once when the model was loaded, once when the texture is loaded dynamically).

Does anyone know how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

> the UV maps seem to be defined, but aren't getting defined in the shader for some reason.

That happens because built-in materials only define the `vUv` varying if maps are sampled in the fragment shader. Since you have removed all maps from your asset, no varying is defined.

One solution to solve the problem is to define the varying manually via `onBeforeCompile()` by overwriting the `uv_pars_fragment` shader chunk with just `varying vec2 vUv;`.

Answer (score 2):

After quite a bit of digging I found I can just set

```
material.defines.USE_UV = '';
```

And it will enable the UVs for the model

Comment: Good idea - some other instances of the problem [here](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/my-instancing-code-is-broken-while-migrating-through-r106-to-r111/11660), the reason why that happens [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/17221) and the "fix" for it in the code [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17237). Unfortunately, even though Three.js is easy when it comes to basic stuff, on more complex issues one (if lucky) must rely on 3 or 4 code contributors who answer here, instead of properly documenting things. Not to mention backward compatibility, which is atrocious.